# REdshift copy command to copy data from a source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've a file in which there is a column with county names in truncated format like India as IN, North america as NA.

While copying the data in to table using copy command NA is treated as Null.

Is there any way to get the data as is.

Comment: Are you sure that NA is treated as Null?

Comment: Yes, it's been treating NA as null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NULL AS 'null_string'` to declare a different `NULL` string.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as